# Android - DrawerLayout and SlidingUpPanel together

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I have a Main activity at the moment which uses a DrawerLayout navigation, this can be used to open up multiple fragments in the FrameLayout, this works great.

However i now need the ability to have a SlidingUpPanel on the same activity to display some media playback controls. The documentation for DrawerLayout and SlidingUpPanel both state that each need to be the root item in the Layout file.

Is there a workaround for this that I am missing?

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SlidingUpPanel